# How to do more granular scaling in vis.js network?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vis.js, vis.js-network

I'm building an applet with the vis.js network module. I'd like one node to be *slightly* larger than the rest. I have tried setting its `value` to exactly 1 more than the rest of the nodes on the network, but this gives me a node that is 3 or 4 times the size of the rest. I'd like it to only by 25% or 50% larger than any other node.

Any thoughts?

Comment: My current options seem to be (1) all values the same, all nodes the same size and (2) one node twice or three times the size of all other nodes. Is there some in between setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved through the `scaling` property of a node. Make all nodes have a similar value, but give a scaling field to the node you'd like larger than the rest. Play around with the values until you reach the desired effect.

```
largernode = {
              ...
              value: 50
              scaling : { min: 30, max: 40 }
             }

othernodes = {
              ...
              value: 50
              scaling: undefined
             }
```

documentation: https://visjs.org/docs/network/nodes.html#